# Working with extended models in rails 5.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

**Theme:**

I'm working in a rails app where I have extended a existing model called `profile` into two models called `person` and `organization`. I want to get organizations only when I use `Organization.all` and people only when I call `Person.all`.

**Problem:**

But when I use `Organization.all` or `Person.all` it returns all records without removing person form `Organization.all` and organization form `Person.all`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your looking for is *Single Table Inheritance*. You want `Profile` to be a base class of `Person` and `Organisation` so `class Person < Profile` etc.

You then want a migration to add a type field to profile

```
add_column :profiles, :type, :string, reference: true
```

Then you simply call `Person.all` to get all the people, and `Organisation.all` to get all the organisations.

https://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/ for reference if you have more trouble.